# Is the "Lister Foundation" in "Catcher in the Rye" a real organization?

Tags: historical-context, j-d-salinger, the-catcher-in-the-rye

In Chapter 21 of *Catcher in the Rye*, Phoebe tells Holden about a movie she saw at the "Lister Foundation". No other mention of the Foundation appears in the text. Was it a real organization when Salinger wrote *Catcher*? If not, is it based on another organization, or is it a product of Salinger's imagination?

Answer (score 2):

No obvious organisation of building of that name is found in online searches, though the world is apparently full of Lister Foundations charitably giving grants and drilling wells etc.

I did find a book by Grace Elizabeth Hale called [A Nation of Outsiders: How the White Middle Class Fell in Love with Rebellion in Postwar America](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=koM8DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA312&ots=_MsBOi8onv&dq=%22the%20lister%20foundation%22%20New%20York&pg=PA312#v=onepage&q=%22the%20lister%20foundation&f=false)
which contains the following snippet from a page not included in the Google Books preview:

> The Lister Foundation may refer to the Lister Institute in the UK, which is a medical research charity founded in 1891. I cannot find any reference to a film fitting Salinger's description of *The Doctor*.

It is possible that Salinger had used materials referencing the Lister Institute when researching for Allie's leukaemia and had the name in mind, or it may have been pure invention.